# Lock launch image orientation for iPad

Tags: ipad, launch

I want to know whether there is any way to lock the orientation of only launch screen for iPad just like iPhone. As there is no landscape launch for iPhone I want to achieve a similar behaviour for iPad.

Comment: To clarify: you want to prevent Springboard (the "launch" app) from rotating into a landscape orientation on an iPad?  I'd be very surprised if that were possible.

Comment: Yes I want to lock the rotation of app launch. Is it possible ?